# Functional Dependency lhs has both prime and non-prime attributes

Tags: normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

Consider the table zoo(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) and the FD’s

a → b,d,e,g
c,d → f
f → c
e,g → d

Perform normalization on it.

Candidate keys are {a,c} {a,f}, so primes are {a,c,f}

2NF is violated by a → b,d,e,g

Then new tables are t1(a,b,d,e,g), zoo(a,c,f)

3NF is violated by e,g → d

Then new tables are t2(e,g,d), t1(a,b,e,g), zoo(a,c,f)

BCNF violation is prime -> prime, however, c and f are prime but d is non-prime so that lhs has both prime and non-prime, and rhs is prime.

Then my question is how to deal with the FD  c,d → f?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** You seem to not understand normalization. Your final question sentence doesn't make sense.

1. Normalization to a given NF does not go through lower NFs. (Of course, you might have been told to normalize to 2NF then 3NF then BCNF.)
2. Normalization to a given NF involves following an algorithm that has been proven to get you there. Preferably "preserving FDs". Find an algorithm.
3. After you decompose you have to determine FDs & CKs for each new component. Note also that the FDs that hold are given ones plus those that follow per Armstrong's axioms.
4. "BCNF violation is prime -> prime ..." is unintelligible. Details matter. Find a textbook definition. You are not properly stating/using the BCNF definition involving 3NF and prime attributes.

Find an academic textbook/presentation/course reference for normalization. Follow their definitions & algorithm(s).

Decomposition t2(e,g,d), t1(a,b,e,g), zoo(a,c,f) is in 3NF. (But it doesn't seem like you are following proper normalization procedures.) CK (candidate key) sets are {{e,g}} for t3, {{a}} for t1 and {{c,f}} for zoo. This is BCNF since each non-trivial FD that holds in each table is out of a superkey. (Some problems with your BCNF justification is that you need to address all 3 tables & no table has c, f & d.) FD c,d → f doesn't hold in any table because none has all three of those attributes, so you don't need to do something with it. But there might or might not be a decomposition to BCNF where every FD that holds in the original holds, and maybe every possible decomposition has some FD(s) that don't hold. But you need to learn how to normalize.